# community framework in PHP

Tags: php

I am looking for a framework in php that can give me out of the box implementation of features like:

Adding users to main site.
The users can create individual groups.
Other users can send invitation to join groups. (like linkedin has it)
Group with notice board, pubic and private announcements etc
groups can have different themes etc...

Most of the frameworks that i have seen revolves around blogging (CMS) or stores.

Is there a open source framework that is designed for such use or atleast has these features? (even if it has some features and is opensource i can think of customizing it)

Comment: Do you want a web application framework to help you build such a system, or a ready-made system? They are two different things.

Comment: I am looking fro a ready-made framework (if there is such a framework) else some thing that is close enough so that i can customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Joomla](http://joomla.org) as framework and [JomSocial](http://jomsocial.com) for community solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Drupal](http://drupal.org)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla + [community builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder) could be an option too.